# Nginx rewrite и домены 3-го уровня

Tags: nginx

Не получается сделать реврайт с `http://blabla.mysite.ru/` на `http://mysite.ru/index.php/page/blabla`... Сделал, как в конфиге ниже, но он, по всей видимости, пытается открыть файл `/www/mysite/index.php/page/blabla`, которого, естественно, не существует.

Делаю 302 редирект, но он меняет url в браузере, что не нужно. Как решить проблему?

```
location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
        set $uid "www";
        if ($host ~ "^([a-z0-9\-]+)\.mysite\.ru$") {
            set $uid $1;
        }

        if ($uid !~ "^(www)$") {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/page/$uid last;
        }
    }
```

Comment: почему же, rewrite вполне себе тут обсуждается

Comment: Вам точно нужен реврайт, а не проксирование?

Answer (score 1):

вероятно, вам надо перенаправлять запрос на `/index.php`, передавая остальной путь как параметры запроса. т.е., в этой строке:

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/page/$uid last;
```

надо <kbd>/</kbd> после `/index.php` заменить на <kbd>?</kbd>:

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?page/$uid last;
```